# Access database in android

Tags: android, database

I am designing an android application.I am using SQLite database.
 In my application can I access my database without rooting the device. I know how to get database when running an emulator. can this is possible for devices also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which database are you talking about ? 
If your talking about the local Android database (`SQLite`) yes, you can get access to it and create your table / execute queries. You gonna need to write a class (a `DataBaseHelper`).

It your are talking about a remote database (on your web server so, `MySQL` I think) you may follow those steps (this is the way I use too) :

A*ndroid phone -> .php File -> Database MySQL*

You need to write an **`asyntask`** with **HTTP POST** request to target you *.php* file on the web server. This file will execute your query and construct a **JSON Object** to `return`. The JSON Object will be parse into the AsyncTask to get `Strings`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways to store data on Android OS.

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
```

Please refer to this article for more information.

To summarize,

if you want to use sqlite database(relational database), I recommend using the content resolver.

Also, can you clarify more on

```
"Can I send my database to web server by anyway"
```